# python 3: quoting result of random string generation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and things do not always work as I expect... but I am learning, slowly.  Here is a case in point.  If I randomly create a string via:

```
thing = ''.join([
    random.SystemRandom().choice(
        "{}{}{}".format(
            string.ascii_letters, string.digits, string.punctuation
        )
    ) for i in range(63)
])
```

then I could end up with a string with single quotes as well as backslashes.  I assume that I should then go through the string and quote the possibly problematic characters.  So, for example: if I generate the (short) string:

```
cs]b77e\IM>&4/,u.s_jr"xmMdHD7a'wrEw(
```

my instinct tells me that I should quote that into:

```
cs]b77e\\IM>&4/,u.s_jr"xmMdHD7a\'wrEw(
```

It looks like the `string.replace()` method is my friend...

```
thing = ''.join([
    random.SystemRandom().choice(
        "{}{}{}".format(
            string.ascii_letters, string.digits, string.punctuation
        )
    ) for i in range(63)
]).replace('\\', '\\').replace('\'', '\'')
```

but is there a better way?

Also, in the `replace()` methods the meaning of the single quoted strings seems to change depending on context.  Coming from Perl this seems strange to me.  My initial attempts had me doing things like `replace('\\', '\\\\')` thinking that I had to quote the characters going into the replacement string.  Is this normal or am I missing something else?

**Edit**
My goal here is to end up with 63 characters in a string.  I don't really think that I have to quote any generated single quotes but my thought is that if I later use the string and it has generated backslashes then the next character after the backslash would act like it was quoted, right?  I mean:

```
len('1234')
```

yields `4` but

```
len('12\4')
```

yields `3` so I need to post-process the generated string to at least quote the backslashes, right?  Is there a better way to quote problematic characters than a chain of `replaces()` methods?

Comment: What is your question? What is your goal, even?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is necessary.  If you do `s = '{}{}'.format(string.punctuation[23], 'n')`, it will `print(s)` as `\n`, but the `repr(s)` is `\\n`.  I don't think that you need to worry about these things as if they were string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string can contain any valid characters; the quotes and backslashes are only useful or special when *representing* a string in Python code. So you don't normally need to do anything like this when you already have a string which contains the characters you want.

If you want a representation which can be parsed by Python (e.g. by writing it to a `.py` file), `repr()` does that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape characters unless they are part of code you are writing or from an input from a user.  If the backslash character or a quote character is generated by a Python program, then it is already stored *as that character* in memory.  There is no need do any additional escaping.

Why?  Because Python is not **interpreting** a string literal, it is simply generating characters, which are stored as numbers in memory.  When you ask Python to display a string containing one of the characters such as a single quote or a backslash, it will automatically escape them.

Here is an example.  A double quote is 34, single quote is character 39, and backslash is 92.

```
'a'+chr(34)+'b'+chr(39)+'c'+chr(92)+'d'
# returns:
'a"b\'c\\d'
```

Because I included a double quote and a single quote Python will use a single quote to surround the string, an unescaped double quote within the string, an escaped single quote, and and escaped backslash.

So there is no need to escape characters that are generated within a Python program, it does it for you.